# HTML5 & CSS - Can't make content replace previous content on link click

Tags: html, css

Sorry if it's confusing but I'm not sure how to post it. I want a simple webpage as Resumee/CV. What I want is a single page dispaly, with a navbar menu and content page split in two parts (left image, right information). What I need is to replace the content depeding on each link that has been clicked. I have managed to display everything at once but I can't tie link to content relation. Many thanks for any tip.

**HTML**

```html
 <nav>
  <ul class="fade">
   <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
   <li></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <div class="imagemain">
 <img src="http://spiritfiddle.com/promo/SpiritFiddleLogoFiddler.jpg"</img>
 </div>

 <div id="content">

  <div id="home">
  <span class="font01">HOME</span><br>
  <span class="font02">Wecos vinosec</span><br>
  Excitate vos e somno, liberi mei<br>
  Cunae sunt non<br>
  Excitate vos e somno, liberi fatali<br>
  Somnus non est<br>

 <div id="about">
 <span class="font01">ABOUT</span><br>
 <span class="font02">Wecos vinosec</span><br>
 Excitate vos e somno, liberi mei<br>
 Cunae sunt non<br>
 Excitate vos e somno, liberi fatali<br>
 Somnus non est<br>


 <div id="portfolio">
 <span class="font01">ABOUT</span><br>
 <span class="font02">Wecos vinosec</span><br>
 Excitate vos e somno, liberi mei<br>
 Cunae sunt non<br>
 Excitate vos e somno, liberi fatali<br>
 Somnus non est<br>

 <div id="contact">
 <span class="font01">CONTACT</span><br>
 <span class="font02">Wecos vinosec</span><br>
 Excitate vos e somno, liberi mei<br>
 Cunae sunt non<br>
 Excitate vos e somno, liberi fatali<br>
 Somnus non est<br>

 </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
font-family: 'Droid-sans', sans-serif;
}


/* NAV STYLE*/
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
 left:0;
    width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 0.65em;
 text-align: right;
 border-bottom-color: #D2D2D2;
 border-bottom-style: dotted; 
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

li {
 display: block;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
}

li a:hover {
 color: #00A8FF; text-decoration: none;
 }
 
/* FADE OBJECTS */

.fade li {
   opacity: 1;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }

   /*color: #00A8FF* #00537C*/
   .fade li:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
   color: #00A8FF; text-decoration: none;} 


/* BODY*/

.imagemain{
 position: fixed;
 top: 75px;
 left: 17.5%;
 opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}

.imagemain:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.font01{
 font-size: 2em;
 font-family: Calibri;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: grey;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #C1C1C1;
}
.font02{
 font-size: 1.25em;
 font-family: Open Sans;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

/* FADE PAGES */

#content{
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 75px;
 left: 50%;
 border-left-color: #D2D2D2;
 border-left-style: dotted; 
 border-left-width: 1px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#home, #about, #contact, #portfolio {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 display: none;
}

#home, #about, #contact, #portfolio :focus {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need  `<a id="home"></a>`  right after your `<div id="home">` and same for the rest.

so

`<div id="home">
  <a id="home" class=""></a>
   Your page content goes here.
</div>`
  Also it looks like you forgot to close your `<div>` tags

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately its not working as expected. :(

Comment: That is odd. I wonder why the anchor tag and div id method is not working. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Try closing your `<div>` tags

Comment: Closed div and adjusted anchor and div. Now my nav bar is completly gone bad. Im not using jquery.

Comment: Nevermind, got the solution, overflow: hidden; was missing on the main container my bad